# Why button onlick does nothing in Jade/pug

Tags: javascript, pug

Why my button onclick does nothing?
[enter image description here][1]

```
doctype html
html
  head
  block content
   script.
    function changeToTextBox(){
        alert("Testing");
    }
    title User
    welcome #{name}
  body
  button(onclick="changeToTextBox()") Edit
  form(name="searchFrm", method="post")
     input(type='text', name='email')
     input(type='submit', name='search')
```

Comment: `title` and `welcome` are in your `script` block for starters.

Comment: @mpen that was it! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your indentation.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block content
     script.
      function changeToTextBox(){
          alert("Testing");
      }
    title User
    
  body
    p welcome #{name}
    button(onclick="changeToTextBox()") Edit
    form(name="searchFrm", method="post")
       input(type='text', name='email')
       input(type='submit', name='search')
```

And use a compiler like https://pughtml.com/ to view the HTML output so you can better see what's wrong.